# Windows Server 2012 install updates in wrong time

Tags: windows-update, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried to set up an automatic installation of new Windows updates and reboot after installation on Windows Server 2012. I [followed this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wsus/2013/10/08/enabling-a-more-predictable-windows-update-experience-for-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012-kb-2885694/).

I set installation of new updates on `'4 - Every Wednesday' at 11 PM`. A couple of days ago I checked my server. New updates were installed on the 30/01/2017 8:06 AM (it was Monday). The system was restarted on the 30/01/2017 8:08 AM.

It doesn't make any sense for me. How can I set schedule in another way installation day on Wednesday?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Server 2012 R2 does not automatically reboot after installing Windows Updates](http://superuser.com/questions/940351/windows-server-2012-r2-does-not-automatically-reboot-after-installing-windows-up)

Comment: Not really. On the link which you sent the problem is that server is not restarting automatically. My problem is that new updates are installed in wrong time.

Comment: Apologies. I have noticed that Windows Server 2012 will not restart if someone is logged I.  Can you confirm no-one is left logged in,  even if they're inactive at the time.